# How would I edit HTML files in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

### Background

I am developing a game and I need to have the least possible requests sent to the server, I am making my own file bundler so I can combine separate files like index.html, index.js, and styles.css into a single HTML file where the js would be loaded in the head of index.html inside of script tags <script>like this<\script>. The same would be done with the CSS file but with style tags.

### Problem

NodeJS doesnt have document so I cant just require the html file do ele.appendChild. The only other option that comes to my mind would be using REGEX but I would rather not use that.

### TLDR

I need something that will let me do things like document.head.appendChild to an HTML file in nodejs.

Comment: see [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)

Comment: What is the reason to do this on the backend instead of the fronend?

Comment: "I am making my own file bundler so I can combine separate files like index.html, index.js, and styles.css into a single HTML file" — [This sounds like a waste of time](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/) (and one which will have a negative effect on caching)

Comment: What Quentin said. Please just look at e.g. Rollup instead...

Comment: The HTML file is JUST a text file on your server.  The HTML hasn't been parsed (that happens in the browser) so there's no known structure to the HTML.  It is JUST a text file.  If you want to treat it as fully parsed file, then you'd have to parse it (using a tool like Cheerio or JSDOM) and then modify it and then somehow reconstitute it into HTML to send to the browser.

Comment: Rather than your current approach (trying to use `document.head.appendChild()`, there are existing tools for "bundling" front-end resources to reduce server requests.  These are most commonly used for bundling lots of Javascript into a single file.  Also, don't forget about the benefits of browser caching on script resources.  While a separately downloaded Javascript resource is an extra server request the first time the page is loaded, the browser can then cache it so on subsequent pages that use the same script file, it doesn't have to be requested from the server again.

Comment: Browser caching of a separate file can be more efficient than bundling into the original HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the JSDOM package. I am now aware of the advantages that sending multiple files can have, like browser caching. However this is a trade off that I need to make due to having amazing response times to begin with and very limited requests, plus this is just a side project.